# When using mathematical induction, is there an example where it is not true that an example on n + 1 can be built based on an example on n?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, induction

I was told that while we are taught induction with the following inductive step:

"Assume that for every instance on $n$, $P(n)$ holds. Then, add $1$ to the instance on $n$, to get an instance on $n+1$. We can say $P(n+1)$ also holds because..."

That this makes a fundamental assumption: That all instances on $n+1$ can be "built" using instances of $n$. Thus, I was told that it is always better to instead "go down" when doing induction, that is, do the following:

"Take any instance on $n + 1$, and remove an arbitrary $1$. Then, by assumption, $P(n)$ holds. Then, add the previously removed $1$ back to the instance on $n$, to get our original instance on $n+1$. We can say $P(n+1)$ also holds because..."

Now, I am confused by why this is necessary, are we not "building" the instance on $n+1$ based on the instance on $n$ that we had obtained when removing an arbitrary $1$ from our $n+1$ instance? In other words, by the fact that we can say "we are able to create an instance on $n$, and $P(n)$ applies on all instances of $n$", then isn't it true that for all instances on $n+1$, there must exist an instance on $n$ where $P(n)$ holds, such that we can add $1$ to it to create that instance of $n+1$?

If that is not the case, can one give an example where it is incorrect to assume that this is the case, and in fact, there exists some instance for some particular $n+1$ such that it cannot be built on an instance of $n$ where $P(n)$ holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given a context, but by the sounds of it ("remove an arbitrary 1"), you're not just talking about numbers.

In graph theory, for example, you have to be careful with how you're constructing your objects. Here's a fallacious proof taken from [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94742/examples-of-interesting-false-proofs):

> Theorem: every graph without isolated nodes is connected.
>
> Proof: Induction on the number of nodes. Clearly the result is true for graphs with 1 (void statement) and 2 nodes. Now, assume we have proved the statement for graphs with up to n nodes. Take a graph with n nodes; by induction hypothesis it must be connected. Let's add a non-isolated node to it. As this node is not isolated, it is connected to one of the other n nodes. But then it's easy to conclude that the whole graph of n+1 nodes is connected!

Comment: You are correct, we are in a graph theory setting. Thanks very much, this clears it up for me a lot.